# Using native sql in java criteria predicate

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, criteria

I have a predicate(**javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate**) which filters raw data as follows:

```
    public Predicate byAccountsId(Collection<Long> accountsId) {
        ParameterExpression<?> param = createParam(AOraArrayUserType.class, new AOraArrayUserType(accountsId));
        return criteriaBuilder().or(
                criteriaBuilder()
                        .equal(criteriaBuilder().function("in_ex", Long.class, actSourceJoin().get(Account_.id),
                                param), 1),
                criteriaBuilder().equal(
                        criteriaBuilder().function("in_ex", Long.class, actDestinationJoin().get(Account_.id),
                                param), 1));
    }
```

This predicate builds the next part of the query:

```
..
where
..
act.source_id in (accountsId.values())
or act.destination_id in (accountsId.values() - array ids)
..
```

It works fine but there may be too much raw data.I want to use "Oracle functional index", which removes unnecessary data from the query results. I tried to rewrite my predicate as follows:

```
    public Predicate byAccountsId(Collection<Long> accountsId) {
        ParameterExpression<?> param = createParam(AOraArrayUserType.class, new AOraArrayUserType(accountsId));
        return criteriaBuilder().or(
                criteriaBuilder().literal(
                        Restrictions.sqlRestriction("case when state != 'ARCHIVE' then source_id else null end"))
                        .in(param));
    }
```

Resurlt query builds fine but returns no result. But when I copy result query to sql developer and run the query it returns the expected result.

Part of the query which is build by new predicate:

```
..
where 
..
(case when act.state != 'ARCHIVE' then act.source_id else null end) in (accountsId.values() - array ids)
..
```

Does anybody know why I don't get the correct result when I'm using the new predicate?
And can I use `hibernate.criterion.Restrictions` with `javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `@Formula` for the expression in your Entity (AOraArrayUserType) and use the field in criteria

```
Restrictions.in("theFormulaField", param)
```

Comment: thank. Result code follows:

`@Formula("CASE WHEN state = 'ARCHIVE' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END")
 private boolean archived;`
and using this formula:
`criteriaBuilder().equal(root().get(Act_.archived), false);`